# SQL query to find if a date falls between two others

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table that I'd like to run a SQL query on. I want to find all the customers that have a status `active` and have their interval_type set to `interval`. That part is fine, it's the next part I'm struggling with.

I want to find any orders that are to be processed between between Dec 1st 2019 and Dec 6th 2019.

The difficulty is that in my table I have the columns "interval", this can be a number between 15-75 days (and is converted to seconds) and when their order was last processed (also a unix timestamp) in the column called "last_processed".

If the "interval" (in seconds) is added to the "last_processed" (a date), does that new date fall between the 1st and 6th of Dec. How can I do that?

```
SELECT *
FROM subscriptions 
WHERE
    status = 'active' AND
    interval_type = 'interval' AND
    `interval` BETWEEN 1575158400 AND 1575676740;
```

Here's what the data looks like in my table:

[image]

Comment: It is quite unclear what you want interval is what time unit seconds years . Also you should always provide some data see https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query

Comment: @nbk I've updated the question, interval is in seconds and last processed is a date. I'll add some data now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it this way

```
SELECT *,
FROM_UNIXTIME(last_processed+`interval`)
FROM subscriptions
WHERE status = 'active' AND
    interval_type = 'interval'
    AND (last_processed + `interval`) BETWEEN  UNIX_TIMESTAMP('2019-12-01 00:00:00')
    AND   UNIX_TIMESTAMP('2019-12-06 23:59:59');
```

[DBfiddle Example](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=e98ff4e7dc071bd64fea5f3e1026d979)

Next time please use text instead or directly a dbfiddle example, than you can get an answer much earlier. That's why i posted the link for a minimal example.